# javafx set parent borderpane to null

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

i have 2 fxml

FXML A:
it contains borderpane with ID fx:id="UnitBorderPane"

FXML B:
it contains anchorpane with ID fx:id="UnitForm"

i load the "FXML B" at borderpane A on the left side

```
FXMLLoader loader = new
FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/projectname/unit/UnitForm.fxml"));
Pane pane = (Pane) loader.load();
UnitBorderPane.setLeft(pane);
```

it is kind of fxml form, so we have a button with action

```
<Button layoutX="102.0" layoutY="169.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#saveUnit" text="Save" />
```

**how to hide that FXML A BorderPane left?**

```
@FXML
private void saveUnit(ActionEvent event) {    
    BorderPane borpane = (BorderPane)UnitForm.getParent().lookup("#UnitBorderPane");
    borpane.setLeft(null);
}
```

this code not work, the borpane variable is null so i cannot set the borderPane FXML A Left to null.

Comment: Shouldn't it just be `BorderPane borpane = (BorderPane)UnitForm.getParent();`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it should just be

```
BorderPane borpane = (BorderPane)UnitForm.getParent();
```

However, none of this feels very robust; for example if you decide to change the layout structure at all you will likely have a lot of code to change in various classes. I would add a property to the controller for `UnitForm.fxml` that you can observe from the controller for `UnitBorderPane`. Something like:

```
public class UnitFormController { // your actual class name may differ....

    private final BooleanProperty saved = new SimpleBooleanProperty();

    public BooleanProperty savedProperty() {
        return saved ;
    }
    public final boolean isSaved() {
        return savedProperty().get();
    }
    public final void setSaved(boolean saved) {
        savedProperty().set(saved);
    }

    // other code as you already have...

    @FXML
    private void saveUnit() {
        setSaved(true);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Then you do

```
FXMLLoader loader = 
    new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/projectname/unit/UnitForm.fxml"));
Pane pane = (Pane) loader.load();
UnitFormController controller = loader.getController();
controller.savedProperty().addListener((obs, wasSaved, isNowSaved) -> {
    if (isNowSaved) {
        UnitBorderPane.setLeft(null);
    }
});
UnitBorderPane.setLeft(pane);
```

Now the management of the `UnitBorderPane` is all in one place, instead of being split over two controllers, and there are no lookups (which are not robust). The controller for the `UnitForm` just sets a property and lets the other controller respond as it sees fit.